# gmail ignoring emails from a php contact form

Tags: php, forms, email, gmail, html-email

We use a php email form on a website, it works fine when delivering email to other email programs, just not gmail, ive checked the spam and the inbox, but i get nothing, its as if gmail dosnt trust the email and completly ignores it. How can we get them to come through ?

the code im using for the form is :

```
<div id="contact-form">
<form id="commentForm" action="assets/php/mail.php" method="POST">
<input type="text" name="name" class="required" placeholder="Name..">

<input type="text" name="email" class="required email" placeholder="Email..">

<input type="text" name="phone" class="required" placeholder="Phone..">

<textarea name="message" placeholder="Message.." class="required"></textarea><br />

<input class="subm" type="submit" value="Submit..">
</form>
</div>
```

and the php is

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>Contact Form Confirmation</title>

<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="4; url=http://www.domain.co.uk">
</head>

<body>

<?php $name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$phone = $_POST['phone'];
$message = $_POST['message'];
$formcontent="
<h1>From :</h1> $name \n
<h1>Email :</h1> $email \n
<h1>Phone :</h1> $phone \n 
<h1>Message :</h1> $message
";

$recipient = "studio@domain.co.uk";
$subject = "Contact Form";
$mailheader = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
$mailheader .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=iso-8859-1" . "\r\n";
$mailheader .= "From: $email \r\n";
mail($recipient, $subject, $formcontent, $mailheader) or die("Error!");

echo("<p>Thanks for getting in touch, we'll get back to you shortly..</p>");
?>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Maybe constructing valid HTML for the $formcontent would help?  Have you tried adding `<html></html>` and `<body></body>`?

Comment: arnt they already in there ? html open 2nd line, body open 10th line, closing last 2 lines ?

Comment: they are there for the document you're displaying to the user, but not in $formcontent! But, more importantly check the answer from TheSmose, he probably has what you're looking for!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

GMail is not the only mail service that will ignore sendmail emails.

Likely, the cause is that your From: header doesn't match your mail server host name.  If you're using 3rd-party hosting, you should find out the host name (e.g. "myhost.com") and use that in your From: header.  Then use the correct email address in the "Reply-To" header instead.

```
$mailheader .= "Reply-To: Some One <someone@mydomain.com>\r\n"; 
$mailheader .= "Return-Path: Some One <someone@mydomain.com>\r\n"; 
$mailheader .= "From: Some One <mydomain@myhost.com>\r\n"; 
$mailheader .= "Organization: My Organization\r\n"; 
$mailheader .= "Content-Type: text/plain\r\n";
```

To increase deliverability, you should use SMTP to send a mail via an actual email account.

To absolutely maximize deliverability, you should use an ESP.

Answer (score 1):

Another (simpler) possibility... try using the -f option:

```
mail($recipient, $subject, $formcontent, $mailheader, "-f {$email}") or die("Error!");
```

Comment: thanks for the responses, could you tell me pros / cons of the -f option ? Also with the smtp email is that done using a server side script ?

Answer (score 0):

I just answered a similar question in here:

[Sending via email info from a contact form with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14679901/sending-via-email-info-from-a-contact-form-with-php/14680042#14680042)

Just check it out i believe it has all the code you need to solve your problem, at least if you dont expect big volume of emails.